# How does NLB -> ALB actually work ? ALB allows only HTTP, HTTPS, WebSockets and NLB supports only TCP, TLS, UDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

If we need static IP address in AWS for Load balancer then we have to go for Network Loadbalancer forwarding requests to Application Loadbalancer.

Now since ALB only supports HTTP and HTTPS protocols
And
NLB only supports TCP protocol

How does this communication actually work?

The client like browser will send the request in HTTP or HTTPS.
How does this communication happens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTTP/HTTPS` runs on top of `TCP`.  If you check [Open Systems Interconnection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), `HTTP/HTTPS` are at the top application layer, whereas `TCP` is at transport layer.

ALB supports only  application layer (HTTP/HTTPS in that case), while NLB works on transport layer (TCP/UDP). Thus NLB can load balance anything above TCP as well. This include `HTTP`, `SSH`, `FTP` and so on.

There is no protocol conversion between TCP and HTTP, as they work on different layers. So everything happens transparently.

Comment: ahh, that's why the LISTNER in NLB is always TCP but the target group which NLB forwards the request to is HTTP/HTTPS. Thanks a lot @marcin

Comment: Magic as they say :D Love the transparent answer haha